# How to calculate the Week number Starts from Saturday instead of Sunday in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to add a column to show the week number of the year in my procedure.

By default the SQL Server considers the week starts as Sunday and shows the week number.

But I need to calculate the week number starts from Saturday.

Code:

```
select datepart(week,'11-july-2020')
```

Output I get:

```
 28
```

Output I need:

```
 29
```

It should start considering from the week starts as Saturday and ends on Friday.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SET DATEFIRST 6;

select datepart(week,'11-july-2020');
```

It allows you to set the first day of the week to a number from `1` through `7`, where `1` is Monday and 7 is `Sunday`.